# Real Effective Exchange Rates Based on Manufacturing Consumer Price Index for India

Tags: macroeconomics, inflation

This question is from [here](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/CCRETT01INM661N)

What does "Real Effective Exchange Rates Based on Manufacturing Consumer Price Index for India " this mean? Does it mean the value of exports adjusted for inflation?